# H5PY problem saving composite numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

In an attempt to reverse-engineer a file format, I have arrived at a following minimal example for creating a composite numpy datatype and saving it to HDF5. The original file seems to be storing datasets of the below data type. However, I do not seem to be able to write such datasets to a file.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

data = ("Many cats".encode(), np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
data_type = [('index', 'S' + str(len(data[0]))), ('values', '<f8', (20,))]

arr = np.array(data, dtype=data_type)
print(arr)

h5f = h5py.File("lol.h5", 'w')
dset = h5f.create_dataset("data", arr, dtype=data_type)
h5f.close()
```

This code crashes with the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "test.py", line 13, in 
>           dset = h5f.create_dataset("data", arr, dtype=data_type)
>         File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line
>   116, in create_dataset
>           dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
>         File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line
>   75, in make_new_dset
>           shape = tuple(shape)
>       TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: You need to use `f.create_dataset('foo1', data=arr)` syntax.  WIthout a keyword, the second argument is assumed to the shape.  So always use `data=` when providing the actual array.

Answer (score 0):

I restructured/reordered your code to get it to work with `h5py`.
The code below works for 1 row. You will have to adjust to make the number of rows a variable.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

data = ("Many cats".encode(), np.linspace(0, 1, 20))
data_type = [('index', 'S' + str(len(data[0]))), ('values', '<f8', (20,))]

arr = np.zeros((1,), dtype=data_type)
arr[0]['index'] = "Many cats".encode()
arr[0]['values'] = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)

h5f = h5py.File("lol.h5", 'w')
dset = h5f.create_dataset("data", data=arr)

h5f.close()
```

Comment: I don't think there was a problem in creating `arr`.  A scalar, 0d, array is fine.  The problem was in calling `create_dataset`.  You use `data=arr`, he didn't.